# span position inside a flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm having troubles with one of a my flex items.

I'm trying to position the 2 `spans`  of my flex div so that one is above the other, but it looks like the properties of `flex` force them to be next of each other.

[Here is what I'm looking to do (the date element)](http://alconis.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/blog_article_with_floating_date.png)

and here is what I have :

```css
#til-container #til-header #til-date-container {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 position: absolute;
 top: 30px;
 margin: auto;
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 border: 1px solid #CCC;
 background: white;
}

#til-container #til-header #til-date-container #til-date {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
 width: 52px;
 height: 52px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background: #d24949;
 color: #FFF;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 900;
 text-align: center;
}

#til-container #til-header #til-date-container #til-day {
 font-size: 20px;
}

#til-container #til-header #til-date-container #til-month {
 font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="til-container">
 
 <div id="til-header">
  <div id="til-date-container">
   <div id="til-date">
    <span id="til-day">25</span>
    <br/>
    <span id="til-month">dec</span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
</div>
```

I've tried several things such has displaying the spans as blocks so they take the full width of the container and force the next span to position below the first one, but that wouldn't work. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using flex, you could add to `#til-date`

```
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
```

I edited your snippet to add it :

```css
#til-container #til-header #til-date-container {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 position: absolute;
 top: 30px;
 margin: auto;
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 border: 1px solid #CCC;
 background: white;
}

#til-container #til-header #til-date-container #til-date {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
 width: 52px;
 height: 52px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background: #d24949;
 color: #FFF;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 900;
 text-align: center;

    /* Added */
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

#til-container #til-header #til-date-container #til-day {
 font-size: 20px;
}

#til-container #til-header #til-date-container #til-month {
 font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="til-container">
 
 <div id="til-header">
  <div id="til-date-container">
   <div id="til-date">
    <span id="til-day">25</span>
    <br/>
    <span id="til-month">dec</span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I wanted to do. I've tweaked the css a bit to smooth it a little bit, then removed the <br/> from the html, and it's perfect ! Thanks.